# Using an object I never defined in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning about building MVC5 web pages using JQuery and Ajax,
in one of my exercises I created this function:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $.get("GetCustomersByJson", null, BindData);

    function BindData(customers) {
        var tbl = $("#customerTable");
        for (k = 0; k < customers.length; k++) {
            var newRow = "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + customers[k].FirstName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + customers[k].LastName + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + customers[k].CustomerNumber + "</td>" +
                "</tr>";
            tbl.append(newRow);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Its basically loading some "Customer" objects using Json and adds them to the table after loading them.

My problem is with the `BindData` function, it gets the `customers` parameter but how does it connect with the `$.get("GetCustomersByJson", null, BindData);` line?

I understand it's probably basic JS knowledge but i still can't find the answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your giving the function to the $.get() method as a success callback.  When the ajax returns it executes that method, providing it with the response data.

Comment: And i can call this response data in any name i like?

Comment: It's a function parameter.  You can name it anything to your hearts content, :) ...that is a valid variable syntax of course, :D